# PrimeReact - Problem with datatable and lazy loading

Tags: reactjs, sorting, datatable, lazy-loading, primereact

I have a problem with DataTable and lazy loading.

When I activate the lazy loading paramater (which i can't remove because the request from the api is too big) the filtering and sorting does not work when the lazy loading is activated. I understand why it works like that, but I really have no idea how to fix it.

If you have any solutions I take it beacause I'm really stuck here :)

link to codesandbox -> https://codesandbox.io/s/datatable-t92wk

I made some modifications with the base exemple in primereact like adding lazy loading, removing paggination and replace it by virtual scrolling. I also made a modification with the filtering but I think that what I did is not really correct, but it works in that case : it stops the lazy variable and therefore I can use lazy loading.

What I would love to do is to sort already loaded data in the table :)

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had the same issue. Apparently you can't use filtering with lazy loading mode ([link](https://github.com/primefaces/primereact/blob/master/src/components/datatable/DataTable.js#L1253)). Makes sense really.

For sorting, you could pass an `onSort` function and everytime a sort event happens (i.e: user clicks on the column header), you can send back a DB request.

```js
const onSort = (e) => {
 // use e.sortField and e.sortOrder to send a DB request,
}

<DataTable onSort={onSort} ... // rest of the stuff />
```